# What is wrong with the logic of my character changing function?

Tags: javascript

I've tried to create a character changing function for strings, it suppose to change all the "-" to "_", and it only does it for the first character and leaves the rest. If someone could explain it would be grate.

```
function kebabToSnake(str) {
    var idNum = str.length;
    for(var i = 0; i <= idNum; i++) {
        var nStr = str.replace("-", "_");
    }
    return nStr;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var nStr = str.replace("-", "_");
```

So, on each iteration, you're replacing the first found `-` character *in the original string*, not the string that you've already replaced characters from already. You can either call `.replace` on just one variable that you reassign:

```js
function kebabToSnake(str) {
    var idNum = str.length;
    for(var i = 0; i < idNum; i++) {
        str = str.replace("-", "_");
    }
    return str;
}
console.log(kebabToSnake('ab-cd-ef'));
```

(note that you should iterate from `0` to `str.length - 1`, not from `0` to `str.length`)

Or, much, *much* more elegantly, use a global regular expression:

```js
function kebabToSnake(str) {
  return str.replace(/-/g, '_');
}
console.log(kebabToSnake('ab-cd-ef'));
```

Comment: Thank you, I see what I've messed up now.